# Flutter - DropdownButton onChanged does not call a function

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a simple DropdownButton element and onChange event.

```
onChanged: (String newValue) {
    if (newValue == "Log out") {
        print("Inside IF");
        setState(){
            user.navigateToPreviousPage(Login(), context, false);
        }
    }
},
```

But from here I only get this print("Inside IF")... It does not call function which should remove user's token and navigate to login page.
In addition, there are no errors or warnings...

What is wrong here? My whole class is Stateless Widget. Should I change it to Stateful?

Comment: The class where you have onChanged method is Stateless? then how are you calling setState?

Comment: I've translated it to Stateful Widget, but still behavior is the same.

Comment: can you add a log inside `navigateToPreviousPage` method to check if it is being called?

Comment: It's not called. Type of that function is `Future<void>`. Could this be a reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling setState in a wrong way:

```
setState(){
            user.navigateToPreviousPage(Login(), context, false);
        }
```

Correct way:

```
setState(() {
  user.navigateToPreviousPage(Login(), context, false);
});
```

And you should call `Navigator.pop` from the widget you want to dismiss :)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but still it doesn't work. It calls the function though but no redirect to another widget. That function simply should do that - `Navigator.pop(context, true);`

Comment: You should call Navigator.pop inside the widget you want to dismiss

Comment: That works... Could you please edit your answer, so I can approve it :) ... Thanks!

Comment: i apply same code of setState() but still its not calling method in flutter